# Why do Dwellers return from the Wasteland by themselves?

Tags: fallout-shelter

In Fallout Shelter why do some Dwellers return from the wasteland by themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Something changed b4 they could stay out as long as possible but now You have to have enough storage available even if you haven't collected items from dwellers in the wasteland.. I upgraded my storage and now my dwellers will stay out as long as I want or till they die..

Comment: machine75 ....I tried that, updated rooms ext nothing's changed